# Using React typescript and populating components from backend request

Tags: reactjs, typescript

So i am currently building a react app and have dynamic data which is built from a backend service.

I currently have a model defined as below:

```
    interface ComponentNameProps {
   name:string;
}

interface IComponent {
    ref: string;
    componentName: ComponentNameProps
}

export default interface IListModel {
    // required by every component
    ref: string;
    component: FC<IComponent>;
```

Within the IListModel I need to have the component to render so in my backend response it looks like the following screenshot

[image]

As seen in the image it shows the title.tsx component which is what is mapped to once data is returned and mapped to the component before it comes into the page.

So in psuedo code i wanted the element to render on the page like so but it does not seem to work with `FC` being assigned to component. I have also tried to add `React.ComponentType` but still no joy. Is this the correct way of doing it? I cannot seem to render the component

```
{componentList.map((item, index) => {
                            if(item) {
                       
                                const { componentName,  ref } = item;

                               
                                return (
                                    <componentName>abcde</componentName>
                                );
                            }
                        })}
```

Any help with with this would be great?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear to me from the above whether `componentName` is actually a React component (a JS function that gets an array of `props` passed to it, that can use Hooks, that returns JSX).  If `componentName` is actually a React component, then you can invoke (run) the component (function) directly yourself with:

```js
{componentList.map((item, index) => {
  if(item) {
    const { componentName,  ref } = item;
    return (
      componentName( {children: "abcde"} )
    );
  }
})}
```

Here you are simply invoking the function `componentName()` directly yourself instead of having the JSX engine translate `<componentName>` into that same function call.

Comment: thanks for that but it states componentName is not a function
TypeError: componentName is not a function

Comment: So what is `componentName` ?  Maybe console `typeof componentName` ?

Comment: The type is an object